# Sum of independent Binomial and Geometric distributions

Tags: probability

This is a question from a mock test in my Intro to Probability coure:

Let $X$~$Bin(26,\frac{1}{23})$ and $Y$~$Geo(\frac{1}{2})$ be two independent random variables. Let $Z=X+Y$. Calculate $\Bbb{P}[Z=46]$.

My initial solution:

$\Bbb{P}[Z=46] = \Bbb{P}[X+Y=46] = \sum_{k=0}^{26}{\Bbb{P}[X+Y=46, X=k]} = \sum_{k=0}^{26}{\Bbb{P}[Y=46-k]\cdot\Bbb{P}[X=k]} = \sum_{k=0}^{26}{(\frac{1}{2})^{46-k}\binom{26}{k}(\frac{1}{23})^{k}(\frac{22}{23})^{26-k}} $

I got stuck calculating this sum. If anyone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to get the desired answer. Note the following: $$\sum_{0 \leq k \leq 26} (\frac{1}{2})^{46 - k} \binom{26}{k} (\frac{1}{23})^k (\frac{22}{23})^{26 - k} = (\frac{1}{2})^{20} \sum_{0 \leq k \leq 26} (\frac{1}{2})^{26 - k} \binom{26}{k} (\frac{1}{23})^k (\frac{22}{23})^{26 - k} = \frac{1}{2^{20}} \sum_{0 \leq k \leq 26} \binom{26}{k} (\frac{1}{23})^k (\frac{11}{23})^{26 - k} = \frac{1}{2^{20}} (\frac{1}{23} + \frac{11}{23})^{26} = \frac{1}{2^{20}} \frac{12^{26}}{23^{26}},$$ which can be further simplified to give $\dfrac{2^{32} 3^{26}}{23^{26}}.$

Digressing a little from your very particular example, the question of determining the distribution of the sum of two **continuous** random variables is a very interesting one and it is one of the places where the *convolution* of two functions proves itself once again to be quite an useful tool. For references, you might want to start by reading this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. Could you please elaborate on how did you make the transition from the last summation?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are interested in the transition from $\binom{26}{k} (\frac{1}{2})^{26 - k} (\frac{1}{23})^k (\frac{22}{23})^{26-k}$ to $\binom{26}{k} (\frac{1}{23})^k (\frac{11}{23})^{26-k}.$ Here I did nothing more than multiplying $(\frac{1}{2})^{26 - k}$ with $(\frac{22}{23})^{26-k}.$ I hope I understood correctly, but if not do let me know.

Comment: Hi, I meant going from $\frac{1}{2^{20}} \sum_{0 \leq k \leq 26} \binom{26}{k} (\frac{1}{23})^k (\frac{11}{23})^{26 - k}$ to  $\frac{1}{2^{20}} (\frac{1}{23} + \frac{11}{23})^{26}$. Thank you

Comment: This is just the binomial formula.